# Display only the current item div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').hover(function () {
        $(this).children('div:first-child').show();
    }, function () {
            $( this ).find('div').hide();
    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2 <div class="action hide">New | Delete</div>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 2.1</li>
            <li>Item 2.1 <div class="action hide">New | Delete</div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>   

</ul>
```

When I move the mouse in Section 2.1 it is also showing the `<div class="action hide"> New | Delete </ div>` Item 2, and I do not want to show, how do I?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works reasonably well, depending on your overall circumstances:

```
var $last_action;
$('li').hover(function() {
    $last_action = $('div.action:visible').length ? 
                   $('div.action:visible') : 
                   $last_action;
    $last_action && $last_action.hide();
    $(this).children('div:first-child').show();
}, function() {
    $last_action && $last_action.show();
    $(this).find('div').hide();
});​
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BChT9/)